# Spring boot startup Exception ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am getting the following exception when I try to start my spring boot application.

> 020-05-11 10:29:25 ERROR
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure:826 -
>   Application run failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to process import candidates for configuration class
>   [com.acme.ecom.gateway.EcomApiGatewayApplication]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]
>   cannot be opened because it does not exist    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:609)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:310)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   com.acme.ecom.gateway.EcomApiGatewayApplication.main(EcomApiGatewayApplication.java:62)
>   [classes/:?] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]
>   cannot be opened because it does not exist    at
>   org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:695)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getRelated(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1089)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1070)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:548)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:521)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:310)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     ... 17 more

Please refer the following **Pom.xml file**

```
...
    <groupId>com.acme.ecom</groupId>
        <artifactId>Ecom-gateway</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>Ecom-gateway</name>
        <description>Api Gateway</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> 
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <slf4jVersion>1.6.1</slf4jVersion>
            <log4j2Version>2.7</log4j2Version>
            <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

            <!-- Hyystrix -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

                <!-- oauth -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Config server -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>
                     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                 <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                 <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                 <version>2.9.0</version>
             </dependency>

               <!-- Ecom-common -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.acme.ecom</groupId>
                <artifactId>Ecom-common</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
               <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
               <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
            </dependency>


          </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are missing `spring-boot-autoconfigure`

Comment: Didn't help :-(